# How to disable my internal wifi card?

Tags: wireless, networking, realtek

I'm running a realtek rtl8188ee, and considering how many problems people are having with it that I read, I decided to order a Panda wireless usb. It should be in the mail today or tomorrow, so I'd like to be prepared to just pop it in and start using it.

Here's the card info

```
#05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0191]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

I'm running off ethernet till I get it so won't be without internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable your wireless card, blacklist its driver. From a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8188ee"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtl8188ee
exit
```

We hope the tricky rtl8188ee will improve so that you can use your internal device. Please check back in a few months.