# Internet is not working anymore

Tags: 14.04, server

Yesterday I've installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 on my laptop (Dell, 2.6Ghz Quad-Core, 8GB RAM).
I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3)
Everything worked fine after I finished the tutorial, I could connect to FTP using another PC, I even installed Wordpress using another PC.

The strange thing happened when I turned On my laptop today morning.
Now, I can't connect to FTP, actually I can't do anything (even `apt-get update` ) which gave me a thought that I have no internet connection.

I've tried to disconnect my another PC (Windows) who is connected to the same network router as my laptop (Ubuntu Server), that didn't worked out.

Please, since I am a **TOTAL beginner** in Ubuntu Server stuff, **tell me which information do I have to provide you more it order to solve this problem**?
I checked various websites (even some of topics here on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)), but none of those helped me to solve the problem.

**EDIT:** I just reboot my laptop again, and everything is **WORKING FINE NOW**, can somebody tell me a reason why this could happen at all?

**EDIT2:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/10802702 (syslog)
**EDIT3:** My `ip addr`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10802731

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic and post additional information.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen please check my EDIT note, everything is working now again, after I reboot my system (20th time today), and I have no idea why it's working now...

Comment: @ElderGeek yeah I know how StackExchange works, that's why I wrote that since I am a total beginner you guys can just tell me what information do you need (since I don't really know). And thanks for welcoming me ;)

Comment: `dmesg` might provide some clues as well as `cat /var/log/syslog |grep error`

Comment: @ElderGeek both of those gives A LOT of information, the second one gives a lot of errors. Want me to upload it to pastebin?

Comment: Ouch! my syslog grep error shows only 1 entry... Perhaps you could narrow it down to  only the last hour of errors by `cat /var/log/syslog | grep error> errlist.tmp` and opening errlist.tmp with gedit as `gksu gedit /var/log/errlist.tmp` and cutting and pasting the info or a pastebin link into an [edit] of your question.

Comment: @ElderGeek I just did that, you can take a look if you click on the link I provided in Edit2

Comment: it all seems to start with b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -524 You may find this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: @ElderGeek is there a way to just disable my wireless card? Since I am not using it at all

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/443268/how-to-disable-my-internal-wifi-card

Comment: I did all that, I hope I won't have any problems in future about that. Thank you a lot. Please post your comments as answer so i can mark it, please. @ElderGeek

Comment: Please upvote the answers that helped you from those questions that I provided you links for in the comments. Those good people deserve all the credit. I will write up an answer on the off chance it doesn't get closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pastebin files it all seems to start with `b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -524`

This points to a problem with the broadcom drivers. Answers on how to solve that problem are [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

As you say you aren't using your wireless card at all you can disable it with solutions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443268/how-to-disable-my-internal-wifi-card)

You may also wish to check your DNS settings and compare to your ISP's recommendations. Or add Googles public DNS at 8.8.8.8 as shown here if you have a GUI:

[image: DNS]

Or via the CLI by editing /etc/network/interfaces as answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server)